# To show multiple checkbox in flatlist

Tags: arrays, react-native, api, checkbox, flatlist

I'm working on flatlist with checkbox . The checkbox should come checked i.e true and when i uncheck it should push all the checked checkboxes to array . then i need to implement the api and i'll get the uncheck item in the response then i need to show in the flatlist . which item.id will be present in the response that id needs to be uncheck.

the code is

```
   <FlatList
     data={global.data_params}
     renderItem={({ item,index }) =><AlertItem item={item}/>}

   />
```

and componenet is

```
const [state, setstate] = useState(isChecked?isChecked:true)
console.log('state',state)
return (
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row",
marginBottom: 20,}}>
  
    <CheckBox
 
    checked={state}
onPress={() => setstate(!state)}
  
      style={{alignSelf: "center"}}
    />
    <Text style={{    margin: 8,
}}>{item.name}</Text>
  </View> )
```

and when i'll click on the submit i need to pass the array with unselect checkbox and after hiting that api another api will hit which will return the result with uncheck checkbox so my preblem is that how can i show the unselected checkbox from the api second time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Piuzu.png)

and also i need show tick on all the checkbox initially.

Answer (score 1):

first of all make your state as this

```
   power: [
      {value: 0, text: 'low voltage', selected: false},
      {value: 1, text: 'power', selected: false},
      {value: 2, text: 'electricity', selected: false},
      {value: 3, text: 'power button', selected: false},
     
    ],
```

then before your render make new array variable and onchange of checkbox push your selected item in newTrueArray

```
  let newTrueArray = [];
    this.state.power.forEach((val) => {
      if (val.selected) {
        newTrueArray.push(val.value);
      }
    
    });
```

then for updating your check box you can do something like this

```
 updateCheckBox = (index, newSelected) => {
    let newArr = [...this.state.power];
    newArr[index].selected = newSelected;
    this.setState({purpose: newArr});
  };
```

and to show  checkbox option in your UI, do like this

```
 {this.state.power.map((val, index) => {
          return (
            <ListItem noBorder>
              <Left>
                <Text style={{marginLeft: 30, color: 'gray', marginTop: 10}}>{val.text}</Text>
              </Left>
              <Right>
                <CheckBox
                  color="#0080af"
                  onPress={() =>
                    this.updateCheckBox(index, !val.selected)
                  }
                  checked={val.selected}
                  style={styles.check}
                />
              </Right>
            </ListItem>
```

Comment: Hello @ Hammad Hassan
actually the data is coming from api the data is [{"id": 100, "name": "Low Voltage - Occurrence"}, {"id": 200, "name": "Power Restauration"}, {"id": 300, "name": "Power Failure"}, {"id": 400, "name": "Low PF - Occurrence"}, {"id": 500, "name": "REMOTECONNECT"}, {"id": 600, "name": "REMOTEDISCONNECT"}]

Comment: and the api response can't be changed

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put your data in the state like

```
  power: [
      {value: 0, text: {item.firstname}, selected: false},
      {value: 1, text: '{item.secondname}', selected: false},  
    ],
```

Comment: But how can i put the data if it is coming from api and api response can't be changed.